# Can I travel to Switzerland with EU ID?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, switzerland, eu-citizens, identity-cards

I know, that Switzerland and Liechtenstein are not members of EU. However, they are members of Schengen. Schengen rules remove all internal border controls between member countries.

If I travel to Switzerland, must I take my passport with me, or would it be enough to have my personal ID of one of EU countries?

Inside Schengen Area, I don't expect to be stopped for border control. But police can control a car anywhere, and possibly, this is where I might need passport instead of ID.

Comment: As far as I know, Switzerland has no requirement to carry ID with you at all times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on your citizenship. Generally, [the official homepage states](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/dam/data/migration/einreise/merkblatt_einreise/mb-grueezi-e.pdf):

> Foreign nationals require a valid and accepted travel document to
>   enter Switzerland. In addition, a visa is required in certain cases.
>   Furthermore, sufficient funds must be available or procurable by legal
>   means to cover the cost of living during the transit through or the
>   stay in Switzerland. The Swiss Federal Office for Migration (FOM), the
>   Swiss foreign missions and the cantonal migration authorities will
>   gladly provide information on the principal conditions for entry to
>   Switzerland (www.bfm.admin.ch).

Now the question is, what is a valid travel document? This depends on the country. There is a [long list of valid travel documents](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/publiservice/weisungen-kreisschreiben/visa/liste1_staatsangehoerigkeit.html) for each country. Assuming from your profile that you're Polish, a ID card is enough.

Comment: +1 Incidentally, this is not strictly related to either the EU or Schengen agreement. For example, French citizens have been allowed to travel to Switzerland with a national ID card for decades. The bilateral agreements might have extended this possibility to a larger number of countries, though.